# Why aren't my onclick events working?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a snippet of my code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreami/jy69s6r3/2/).

I want the "+ Create Forum" button to show the form, "Cancel" button to reset the form and hide it, and if you want to see the form, delete "style="display: none".

I used a lot of examples out of w3schools and I have tried to use all its examples of writing a show and hide, one of the resets worked but it was a onclick="this.reset()" which wasn't what I wanted because I wanted it to hide too.

```
<html>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="createform">+ Create Forum</button>
<div class="form-group" id="createForum">
<form action="forums.php" method="get" id="forumForm" style="display: none">
<label>Forum name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="forumName">
<label>Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="create">Crear</button>
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" onclick="clearing()">
</form>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#createform").click(function() {
$("#forumForm").show();
 });

function clearing() {
document.getElementById("forumForm").reset();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are using a mixture of jquery and vanilla javascript. Also I would suggest not inline javascript like you have on the input onclick method "clearing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#createform").click(function() {
 $("#forumForm").show();
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="createform">+ Create Forum</button>
<div class="form-group" id="createForum">
<form action="forums.php" method="get" id="forumForm" style="display: none">
<label>Forum name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="forumName">
<label>Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="create">Crear</button>
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" onclick="clearing()">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked, I was missing the jquery link, now I feel really dumb but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @dreami, pls check mark for my solution, if it helped ;) thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery and you have not linked any jquery library to your html.

Try linking this in the head tag and run your code again

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you've done it and the jquery library inclusion is in your head... But best to check it first...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Also, this is not a very good practice to have JS mixed up with HTML in the body. Instead, I recommend to place you JS in the head section and to have your code triggered once your document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#createform").click(function() {
        $("#forumForm").show();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jy69s6r3/5/

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to run jQuery code, but seems you've not included jquery in your code, neither in the fiddle you have provided. Please add this to your head tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Try again and let me know.
I've modified your fiddle, please take a look - [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jy69s6r3/4/)